# Angular - how to pass received JSON in to a html table?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 6 project which I receive a JSON object like the following:
[image: json array]

And now I want to inject/pass this on a html table. Here is my code:

**Interface**

```js
interface Ilivelog {
  instID: string;
  procID: string;
  threadNum: string;
  status: string;
}
```

**The object**

```js
dataAgent: Ilivelog;
```

**Method**

```js
onGetAgent() {
  this.backend.getAgentStatus().subscribe(
    (response: Response) => {
      this.dataAgent = response.json();
      console.log("Arrey Agent: " + this.dataAgent);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  )
}
```

**How I get the data**

```js
getAgentStatus() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/rms_agent/status');
}
```

How can I pass the this json in to a HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the JSON is valid in a validator.

Comment: Yes, this is was the main problem, my backend team was sending me a string not a json...

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your Component Template:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <td>instID</td>
    <td>procID</td>
    <td>threadNum</td>
    <td>status</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of dataAgent">
      <td>{{item.instID}}</td>
      <td>{{item.procID}}</td>
      <td>{{item.threadNum}}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-response-to-table?file=src/app/live-log/live-log.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: didn't help, I got only the thead. I belive that this can't recognise the item.body.

Comment: it says:
Arrey Agent: {"instID":"2018#11#06","procID":1161005,"threadNum":0,"status":9},{"instID":"2018#11#06","procID":1161030,"threadNum":0,"status":9},{"instID":"2018#11#06","procID":1161020,"threadNum":0,"status":9}

Comment: can you help me? There is no result displayed. And the log I have:
Arrey Agent: {"instID":"2018#11#06","procID":1161010,"threadNum":0,"status":9}

Comment: can it be that I need to use httpClientModule on the back end or something?

Comment: import { Http } from "@angular/http";
constructor(private http: Http) { }

Comment: I belie the problem is the response. For example the post man gives me this body:
["{\"instID\":\"2018#11#06\",\"procID\":1161007,\"threadNum\":0,\"status\":2}"]

I can't separate instID, procID and etc... it's like the response is a string.

Comment: When I console.log(this.dataAgent.procID) the log says: undefined

Comment: From what I understood `dataAgent` is an array. So you'll have to print it like this: `console.log(this.dataAgent[0].procID)`

Comment: no because:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instID' of undefined

Comment: @Praetorian1995, I give up. Unless you add a StackBlitz sample replicating the issue, I don't really think it would be possible to help you out.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-response-to-table-t1sc56?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbackend.service.ts

Comment: @Praetorian1995, the stackblitz doesn't really replicate your issue. It doesn't have the actual data that is returned from your API. It also gives me an error saying `src` is missing.

Answer (score -2):

In your component.ts:

```
results$: Observable<Ilivelog[]>;
ngOnInit() {
   this.result$ = this.backend.getAgentStatus().pipe(
        map(res => res.json())
   );
}
```

in your view.html

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let log of (results$ | async)">
       <td>log.instID</td>
       <td>log.procID</td>
       <td>log.threadNum</td>
       <td>log.status</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'. ("

Comment: and then it shows only: log.instID log.procID log.threadNum log.status

Comment: the `.pipe(map(res => res.json()));` should be after the `this.http.get()` not instead of a `.subscribe()`

Comment: If you see getAgentStatus() return an observable. But if you use HttpClient module you don't need to do res.json().